# Writing empty GeoDataFrame to shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, export, geopandas, geodataframe

I don't know why this is so hard to find or to do, but how does one create an empty `.shp` with `geopandas`?

I essentially want to duplicate the processes of creating a type: polygon shapefile from QGIS, but in a Python script. There is no data to append at this stage. I understand the error, but I am not sure how to add data without adding data. Do I need to do something with schema?

```py
def create_empty(save_name):
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['id', 'geometry'], geometry='geometry')
    df.set_crs(4326)
    print(df)
    df.to_file(filename=f'./QGIS_inputs/{save_name}.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

The error that I get:

> ```
> ValueError: Cannot write empty DataFrame to file.
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geopandas derives the schema from the geodataframe if you don't specify it. And since your geodataframe is empty, geopandas can't derive a schema.

If you want to save an empty shapefile, you need to pass a fiona [schema](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.collection.Collection.schema) dict that defines the geometry type and at least one column (that's a shapefile restriction, not applicable to all output formats):

```
import geopandas

shp_fname = "test.shp"
schema = {"geometry": "Polygon", "properties": {"id": "int"}}
crs = "EPSG:4326"

df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[])

df.to_file(shp_fname, driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema, crs=crs)
```

More details on schemas:

- [`fiona.collection.Collection.schema`](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.collection.Collection.schema)
- [format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#format-drivers-crs-bounds-and-schema)
- [writing-new-files-from-scratch](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#writing-new-files-from-scratch)

Comment: Thank you! To follow up, are there other shapefile schemas? Why would geopandas not have a schema? To make it simplier?

Comment: Geopandas derives the schema from the geodataframe if you don't specify it. Geopandas only uses [fiona schemas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file:~:text=If%20specified%2C%20the%20schema%20dictionary%20is%20passed%20to%20Fiona%20to%20better%20control%20how%20the%20file%20is%20written), but you can set up any fiona schema that a shapefile supports.

Answer (score 3):

### GeoPandas < 0.11

Try with Fiona instead:

```
import fiona
import geopandas

shp_fname = "test.shp"
schema = {"geometry": "Polygon", "properties": {"id": "int"}}
crs = "EPSG:4326"

# write an empty polygon shapefile
with fiona.open(shp_fname, "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema=schema, crs=crs):
    pass

# now read in the empty shapefile
df = geopandas.read_file(shp_fname)
```

### After GeoPandas >= 0.11

This [release](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/releases/tag/v0.11.0) can write empty shapefiles:

```
import geopandas

df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    columns=["id", "geometry"],
    geometry="geometry", crs="EPSG:4326")
df.to_file("test.shp")
```

now shows a warning:

> UserWarning: You are attempting to write an empty DataFrame to file. For some drivers, this operation may fail.

Here is the metadata from a system shell with [fio info](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#info):

```
$ fio info test.shp --indent 2
{
  "driver": "ESRI Shapefile",
  "schema": {
    "properties": {
      "index": "str:80",
      "id": "str:80"
    },
    "geometry": "LineString"
  },
  "crs": "EPSG:4326",
  "crs_wkt": "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AXIS[\"Latitude\",NORTH],AXIS[\"Longitude\",EAST],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
  "name": "test",
  "bounds": [
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
  ],
  "count": 0
}
```

Note that this assumes LineString geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, though I marked user2856 due to them using `geopandas`. Do you not need to `save` or `close` after `fiona.open()`?

Comment: @Binx no, because of the `with` statement which is a python `context manager`.

Comment: under the hood, geopandas uses fiona (until [pyogrio](https://github.com/geopandas/pyogrio) is ready)

Comment: So to confirm, the geopandas version (>0.11) can't write empty polygon shapefiles? This is my experience so far, but wanting to confirm it before giving up.